# Blending in Metal: alpha set to 0 is still opaque

Tags: metal

I'm having trouble setting up blending in Metal. Even when starting with the [Hello Triangle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/hello_triangle) example provided by Apple, using the following code

```
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].blendingEnabled = YES;
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactorZero;
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactorZero;
```

and the fragment function

```
fragment float4 fragmentShader(RasterizerData in [[stage_in]]) {
    return float4(in.color.rgb, 0);
}
```

the triangle still draws completely opaque. What I want to achieve in the end is blending between two shapes by using different blending factors, but I thought I would start with a simple example to understand what is going on. What am I missing?

Comment: You're setting those properties in the pipeline state descriptor *before* creating the pipeline state object, right? And then you're setting the pipeline state object on the render command encoder?

Comment: Yes, first the pipeline state descriptor is created and all its properties set and afterwards the pipeline state is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sourceAlphaBlendFactor` and `destinationAlphaBlendFactor` are to do with constructing a blend for the alpha channel. i.e. they control the *alpha* that will be written into your destination buffer, which will not really be visible to you. You are probably more interested in the RGB that is written into the frame buffer.

Try setting values for `sourceRGBBlendFactor` and `destinationRGBBlendFactor` instead. For traditional alpha blending set `sourceRGBBlendFactor` to `MTLBlendFactorSourceAlpha` and set `destinationRGBBlendFactor` to `MTLBlendFactorOneMinusSourceAlpha`

Comment: Thanks! This is somewhat counterintuitive, but makes sense and works perfectly.